# How to force input value to change depending on a change of a third input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the thing. I have an input value that must be equal with another input value. Although, this second input is related to an `onchange` event of another input. E.g:

**Input 1**: Calculates 2+2, 4+4 or any other number
**Input 2**: On change of Input 1, gets its value 
**Input 3**: On change of Input 2, gets its value

The fact is, when the value of Input 2 changes because of Input 1, Input 3 doesn't change, unless I manually change Input 2.

Anyone can help me what is wrong here?

I haven't actually tried something because I don't know any other way of solving this.

```js
function f_mezanino() {

  if (document.getElementById('mezanino').checked) {
    document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").value = "14";
    document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").max = "14";
    document.getElementById("s_alt_max_cum").value = "18";
    document.getElementById("s_alt_max_cum").max = "18";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").value = "11";
    document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").max = "11";
    document.getElementById("s_alt_max_cum").value = "15";
    document.getElementById("s_alt_max_cum").max = "15";
  }
}

function f_legislacao() {
  var alt_max_fac = document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").max;
  document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac_read").value = alt_max_fac;
}
```

```html
<input id="mezanino" type="checkbox" name="s_mezanino" onclick="f_mezanino();"> Utilizar mezanino<br>

<input id="s_alt_max_fac" name="s_alt_max_fac" type="number" value="11" step="0.01" min="0" max="11" onchange="f_legislacao();">

<input id="s_alt_max_fac_leg" name="s_alt_max_fac_leg" type="text" value="11" readonly>
```

Comment: Show your code that tries to do this but isn't working, so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The `change` event only fires when the user changes the value, it doesn't fire when you assign to the value of an input.

Comment: The thing is that I am assigning the value of an input that is being changed by another onchange event. It is changing, just not manually.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't know how to add the code. I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: `ctrl+c` & `ctrl+v` would be enough to add your code. If you're feeling fancy, you can throw a `ctrl+m` in the middle.

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was a correct way of doing it... like for formatting of forum and stuff.

Comment: @apztt Or you can simply put your code to an online editor like JS Bin and paste the shareable link to your post.

Comment: Thanks guys. I used codepen. Here's the link: https://codepen.io/apztt/pen/eYOZbae

Comment: You can use the built-in snippet editor, it's similar to codepen and jsfiddle. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the codepen you provided, you can use [EventTarget.dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) to trigger DOM event manually, remember to check the compatibility.

```
    function f_mezanino() {
        if (document.getElementById('mezanino').checked) {
            document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").value = "14";
            document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").max = "14";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").value = "11";
            document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").max = "11";
        }
        //Dispatch change event here
        var element = document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac");
        var event = new Event('change');
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
   }

   function f_legislacao() {
       //make s_alt_max_fac_leg change with s_alt_max_fac's the value
       var alt_max_fac_value = document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac").value;
       document.getElementById("s_alt_max_fac_leg").value = alt_max_fac_value;
   }
```

If you are able to use jQuery, there is a much shorter way doing this

```
$("#s_alt_max_fac").trigger("change");
```

Comment: It worked just fine! Thanks guys!